# Video does not autoplay in Edge despite use of autoplay attribute

Tags: html5-video, microsoft-edge

I make use of HTML5 video to display a large video at the top of a page. It works very well on Safari, IE and Chrome but on Microsoft Edge it won't allow me to autoplay.

I checked if there is any problem with the file which is encoded in h.264 but there aren't any issues. I've tried an example of W3 school which has the autoplay attribute and this works just fine. Also have I fiddled a bit with the attributes, maybe they were in the wrong order.

```
<video id="video" class="intro__video" src="path/to/video.mp4" muted
autoplay loop 
preload="auto" plays-inline></video>
```

When I add the controls attribute, I can start the video manual and it will play with no problems. However, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging I found that slick slider was implemented. Which manipulates the DOM in a specific way that Edge can't autoplay the video.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had find the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Same issue when using Flickity slider. I had to add `/* Workaround for Microsoft Edge Legacy */ if (document.querySelector('.slide video')) { document.querySelector('.slide video').play(); }`

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your above posted code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" class="intro__video" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" muted
autoplay loop 
preload="auto" plays-inline></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge:

[image]

So you can see that your code is working fine. You can also try to make a test with this code with your MS Edge. So it can be possible that your large size video file has any issue with Edge. I suggest you to make a test with small video file to check whether it solves the issue or not. If it solves the issue than you can try to reduce the file size for MS Edge.